# How to combine two Cobra CLIs into one?

Tags: go, go-cobra

I have the following commands for CLI A ([see the real repository](https://github.com/civo/cli)):

```
$ cli-a -h

Usage:
  cli-a [command]

Available Commands:
  command-a1       command description
  command-a2       command description
  command-a3       command description

Flags:
      --config string   config file (default is $HOME/.cli-a.json)
  -h, --help            help for cli-a

Use "cli-a [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

And, for CLI B, I have the following commands ([see the real repository](https://github.com/kubemart/kubemart-cli)):

```
$ cli-b -h

Usage:
  cli-b [command]

Available Commands:
  command-b1       command description
  command-b2       command description
  command-b3       command description

Flags:
      --kubeconfig string   path to kubeconfig file
  -h, --help                help for cli-b

Use "cli-b [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

What I want to do now is, I want the CLI B (and all its subcommands) to be CLI A's subcommands like this:

```
$ cli-a -h

Usage:
  cli-a [command]

Available Commands:
  command-a1       command description
  command-a2       command description
  command-a3       command description
  cli-b            description about cli-b

Flags:
      --config string   config file (default is $HOME/.cli-a.json)
  -h, --help            help for cli-a

Use "cli-a [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

So when user run `$ cli-a cli-b -h`, they will see:

```
$ cli-a cli-b -h

Usage:
  cli-a cli-b [command]

Available Commands:
  command-b1       command description
  command-b2       command description
  command-b3       command description

Flags:
      --kubeconfig string   path to kubeconfig file
  -h, --help                help for cli-b

Use "cli-a cli-b [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

Both repos are in different Go module name/repository. I still want to offer CLI B to users to download if they don't prefer to download and use all features in CLI A.

Most of the work for CLI B (features, bug fixes and etc) will be done in the CLI B repository and I'm thinking to combine/merge them two in my CLI A's CI pipeline (need to think how to do this as well).

If possible, I don't want to change/update anything in CLI A codebase everytime I made changes to CLI B codebase (business logic, CLI flags & etc). I want the CLI A to act just like a proxy server for CLI B (I'm using an analogy here) - where all the business logic are kept inside CLI B codebase.

And, if you look closer at example outputs above, when user runs `$ cli-a cli-b -h` or `$ cli-a cli-b command-bN [-h]`, I don't want the CLI A's root flag (`--config`) to appear and take effect. Instead, I want CLI B's root flag (`--kubeconfig`) to appear and take effect.

**Questions**

1. Is this doable with Cobra?
2. What's the best way to achieve this without adding too much code in CLI A's repository?
3. How's the project structure/tree should look like?
4. Any good examples for me to refer?
5. On high level, what should I do in CLI A's build/CI pipeline to make this happen?

I'd really appreciate all inputs, pointers, examples and external resources here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this, you can maintain both the cli's as different module, there is no need to merge the code.

All you have to do in in `CLI-A`'s root command is

```golang
cliARootCommand.AddCommand(
       cliBPackage.NewRootCommand(),
)
```

And for your second part of the question where the CliA's persistent flag not being part of CliB. We disable flag parsing in CliB and in the `PreRunE` of CliB's root command, we can mark all parent flag hidden and then parse the flags.

```golang
func NewRootCommand() *cobra.Command {
    rootCommand := &cobra.Command{
        Use: "cli-b",
        PersistentPreRunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
            // marking all parent flag hidden
            cmd.Parent().Flags().VisitAll(
                func(f *pflag.Flag) {
                    cmd.Flags().MarkHidden(f.Name)
                },
            )

            // enabling flag parsing
            cmd.DisableFlagParsing = false

            if err := cmd.ParseFlags(args); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            if cmd.Flag("help").Changed {
                err := cmd.Help()
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                os.Exit(0)
            }
            return nil
        },
        RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
            return cmd.help()
        },
    }
    
    //Diasbling flag parsing
    rootCommand.DisableFlagParsing = true

    return rootCommand
}
```